# Xamarin in Visual Studio 2017 - Creating a native app [Help]

Tags: xamarin

So I have been trying to figure out how to create a native project instead of using xamarin.forms.

I can not find the template on cross-platform
[image: I can not find the template on cross-platform]

Trying to create this project gives me an error]
[image: Trying to create this project gives me an error]

The error I am getting
[image: The error I am getting]

Comment: "for more information on enabling these project types...please see the details in the Migration Report" - have you done this?

Comment: The Migration Report does not open, where do I find it?

Comment: usually it is saved somewhere in your project/solution folder

Comment: I searched my whole solution folder. Do not find it anywhere. Why is the error coming up when I got xamarin installed correctly. Creating Xamarin.Forms works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

My problem has been solved. There was an update a few weeks ago that made the process different.

Mainly, you will now have to create the projects one by one:

1. Create the .NET Standard project first
2. To the solution that is created with this project, add both an Android and an iOS project
3. Make sure that you reference the .NET Standard projects in both the Android and iOS ones

Answer (score 1):

Go to Control Panel -> Add/Update Programs -> Right click on Visual Studio -> Modify/Repair -> Find missing frameworks.

Comment: Look up in your list above Crossplatform. You have "Android" there. Select that and it will allow you to create just Android Project. The same with iOS.

Comment: PCL project is share project between Xamarin.Forms that both your Android and iOS projects will have access to. You usually put there Core code and UI Design in XAML for example, so all your pages etc. You can select Shared Project there instead of PCL and that would allow you to create UI in each specific platform.

Comment: I am talking about the Native Button. That does not exist for me when choosing UI

Comment: @Aaron What you need, Support for unsupported project(as you shown in screenshot) or native button enable?

Comment: the unsupported project error is coming up because of I do not have windows sdk installed I think, so it can not create an UWP Project. But I need the native button to continue with my course or create a project without windows phone involved.

Comment: If you on Mac u wont be able to build UWP project. I still dont understand what are you asking for? Native button within your app? When you create project in Xamarin forms, Xamarin controls get translated into Native control, so Xamarin Forms Button will be Native Button on Android and Native Button on iOS. You misunderstanding how Xamarin.Forms work.

Comment: Oh dear! Select CrossPlatform from the list there instead of "Other"...